# Cloud Data Fusion - Errors with quickstart

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm working on testing Cloud Data Fusion in GCP by executing their quickstart tutorial. The tutorial I am following is [here](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/quickstart)

I configured my environment to have all the appropriate permissions and get to the point where my Dataproc cluster is up and running and the job starts.

After a few minutes, the job fails with the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
```

And:

```
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.ChannelException: eventfd_write(...) failed: Bad file descriptor
```

For the second error, I manually changed the 'input' format to be JSON instead of text (like it comes when you import the pipeline from the HUB), but still no luck. The first error I'm not exactly sure whats going wrong.

I have already review the [Creating a Cloud Data Fusion instance](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/create-instance) documentation, but still receive errors.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How long have you been facing this issue?

Comment: @peakstatus: What compute profile are you using for running the data fusion pipeline? Is the instance basic or enterprise? This error means Data Fusion is not able to make ingress connection on port 22. When a pipeline is run, Data Fusion spins up a dataproc instance and copies  resources needed for pipeline execution and executes the pipeline.
1. Are you using the default compute profile?
2. If yes can you check the project firewall rules if it allows ingress connection on port 22? This firewall rule allows ingress connections on port 22 from any source to any instance in the network

Comment: Does the job even start running ? It is not clear if the first connection timeout error is from the source or from the API calls to start the job ...